# How to rename variables on the fly with Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

There were so many videos showing off the new "advanced" and "smart" renaming of variables for languagues like C# in VS 2015 (Win 10), like [here](https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/16263/Visual-Studio-2015-IDE-Changes/17950#.Vb9Xb26qpHw) (under "Renaming improvements"), but for me it doesn't work.

I have ReSharper extension, but I would assume that it should not in any way affect the new renaming features.

Do I have to activate something on preferences? I have been searching everywhere to activate this.

Answer (score 2):

Once you left click and choose Rename a dialog will pop up. Start changing the text and the variable will be renamed to what you want.

Once you are done, click on apply.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the variable
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
3. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> or choose the Rename option in
   the context menu
4. As you change the variable name, you may see the
   variable references in the whole file/project/solution gets changed.